# Xpath - Filter if group-by parameter exists as child of another variable

Tags: xslt, xpath, foreach

I applied a for-each-group to a set of XML to sort. Now I need to add a filter to not process records where the group paramater exists in another variable.  I'm not sure what the correct XPath statement is.  Example XML Input

Input 1 - $XMLRecords

```
<root>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 1-1</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter1</groupby>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 1-2</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter1</groupby>
    </row>    
    <row>
        <field1>Record 2-1</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter2</groupby>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 2-2</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter2</groupby>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 3-1</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter3</groupby>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 3-2</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter3</groupby>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 4-1</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter3</groupby>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 4-2</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter4</groupby>
    </row>
</root>
```

Input 2 - $RecordsToSkip

```
<root>
    <row>GroupByParamter2</row>
    <row>GroupByParamter4</row>
</root>
```

Input 2 Schema

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="row">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="line" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Output - Records needed to process

```
<root>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 1-1</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter1</groupby>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 1-2</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter1</groupby>
    </row>    
    <row>
        <field1>Record 3-1</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter3</groupby>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>Record 3-2</field1>
        <field2>TEXT</field2>
        <groupby>GroupByParameter3</groupby>
    </row>
</root>
```

Here's the current XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="RecordsToSkip" select="bpws:getVariableData('recordsToSkip')"/>
<xsl:variable name="XMLRecords" select="bpws:getVariableData('xmlRecords')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$XMLRecords/*:root/*:row" group-by="groupby">

            <xsl:call-template name="sortData">
                <xsl:with-param name="groupbyparameter" select="groupby"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sortData">
    <xsl:param name="groupbyparameter"/>
    <--! group specific logic -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I guess I'm trying to place an "if groupby is not a child of RecordsToFilter variable"  around the call-template statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want rows to participate, then remove them from your population selection:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*/row[not(groupby=$RecordsToSkip)]" group-by="groupby">
```

That would be easier and faster than trying to skip the group after it is made.

BTW, I am assuming that `$RecordsToSkip` is a node set or sequence or other repeated construct.  It would help maintaining your stylesheet if you added a constraint to the variable declaration that explicitly tells the maintainer about the organization of the variable.

Comment: Hi Ken, I edited my for-each statement to make it more explicit which variable I was referring to.  I'm assuming the predicate is the same/similar? E.g.

    <xsl:for-each-group select="$XMLRecords/*:root/*:row[not(groupby=$RecordsToSkip)]" group-by="groupby">

Comment: For the second, yes it's a single <root> element with 1 to unlimited  <line> elements.  Could you explain a little more what you mean about adding constraints within the XSLT declaration?  Forgive my ignorance, just haven't heard about variable constraints in XSLT before.

Comment: The way you constrain a variable declaration determines the memory organization, sibling relationships (or lack thereof), and ways to access the information you are storing.  The `as=` attribute dictates the sequence type for variable storage.  See the diagram on page 223 of my XSLT book that is available for free download on a "try and buy" basis at http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/training/#ptux ... if you decide not to pay for the book, please delete the copy that you download for free.

Comment: You say "it's a single <root> element with 1 to unlimited <line> elements" ... so then you might have `as="element(line)+"` as the constraint, which with `select=` would indicate to the maintainer that it is a sequence of elements selected from the tree.  If instead of `select=` you had a child `<xsl:copy-of/>` that would produce a sequence of elements that have no sibling relationship between each other.  Which you use depends on the algorithm you plan to engage once you have the variable ... which in this particular example is a simple comparison of a singleton to a sequence.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely download the book and at the very least use it for reference.  It's too bad I didn't learn this programming language in school.

Comment: I have tried to convince institutions to include it in their curriculum, and at one point even started negotiating with a university, but their priorities changed and it seems "too vocational" to be teaching it as a skill. I ask that you not keep the free copy of the book for reference, as the free copy is intended only to convince a candidate purchaser that it is worth a whole US$40 to pay for it ... and it comes with all future editions included at no additional charge. There is also streaming video with 5 hours of free lecture at: http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/links/udemy-ptux-online.htm

Comment: Your assistance was worth more than $40, so I will definitely be purchasing a copy, and watching the lectures, and if there are classes held in my area I will attempt to attend.